# PL/pgSQL function is not working properly

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql, exists

I am writing a function to create tables for a given table count. Before creating a particular table, I want to check whether that table already exists:

```
create or replace function test (numoftables int) returns void as $$
    declare
    i integer;
    begin 
    i:=0;
    while i< numoftables loop
        if not exists (select * from table$i$)  -- check if table exists
        then 
            create table table$i$(
                column1 int,
                column2 int,
                column1 text,
                column2 text,
                column3 text); 
        end if;
    end loop;
end;

$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

When I ran this code it gave me an error.

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "table$i$" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT not exists (select * from table$i$)
> ```

Can anyone tell me how can I change this code to work properly.

Comment: The language name is a regular SQL identifier, which means you should not put it into single quotes. Please use `language plpgsql` instead. The support for single quoted language names might be removed in the future. Btw: why don't you use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can't check table existence like this. Use [pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) system table to check if table exists
- You have to increment i inside your function, or you'll end up with infinite loop

---

```
create or replace function test (numoftables int) returns void as $$
    declare
    i integer;
    begin 
    i:=0;
    while i< numoftables loop
        if not exists (select * from pg_class where relname = 'table' || i::text)
        then
            execute '
            create table table' || i::text || '(
                column1 int,
                column2 int,
                column3 text,
                column4 text,
                column5 text);
            ';
        end if;
        i := i + 1;
    end loop;
end;

$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

I've tried not changed your logic or syntax much, so it's still your function.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0c6f7/1)</kbd>**